# Change keyboard Ubuntu 16.04 VM on Macbook air

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, macbook-air

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04, VM on macbook Air and I'd need to set the keyboard to Italian layout since now it's English US. I tried with System Settings and changed Text Entry, but any of the Italian configurations there is ok for my one years old macbook air.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: At top of your screen is the status bar which should show current language choice ... ( En by default) ... if so hit the widget  En  and pick Italian which should appear if you have installed it using Settings->Text Entry

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried all the Italian configurations, I have in settings,  but none fits the layout of my macbook keyboard.

Comment: So you have spun up Ubuntu as a VM on OSX ... possibly the language settings are a VM setting ?   which VM virtualbox ? is the parent OSX using Italian or En ?

Comment: Supposedly *Italian (Machintosh)* is the right one. What problems have you experienced with that configuration exactly?

Comment: I'm using vmware fusion VM to run Ubuntu 16.04 on OSX Sierra which runs in Italian. I have changed the VM language setting in Text Entry but the Italian configurations look different from my macbook keyboard. Almost all the symbols (like , ; : | / and so on) are in different positions and also the letter M is on the right of L, instead on the mac keyboard M is in the next line after N (as English US configuration).

Comment: Since I'm gonna programming a bit, vim terminal and so on, it's a bit frustrating to have to learn by hearth symbols positions.

Comment: Has anyone an idea? i can't find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here with Ubuntu 16.04 on an iMac and french